# Google Cloud Pub/Sub Python SDK retrieve single message at a time

Tags: python, google-cloud-pubsub

**Problem**: My use case is I want to receive messages from Google Cloud Pub/Sub - one message at a time using the Python Api. All the current examples mention using Async/callback option for pulling the messages from a Pub/Sub subscription. The problem with that approach is I need to keep the thread alive.

Is it possible to just receive 1 message and close the connection i.e. is there a feature where I can just set a parameter (something like a `max_messages`) to 1 so that once it receives 1 message the thread terminates?

The documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#synchronous-pull) doesn't list anything for Python Synchronous pull which seem to have `num_of_messages` option for other languages like Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following example [in this link](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pubsub/subscriber/api/client.html#google.cloud.pubsub_v1.subscriber.client.Client.pull):

```
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

client = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
subscription = client.subscription_path('[PROJECT]', '[SUBSCRIPTION]')
max_messages = 1

response = client.pull(subscription, max_messages)
print(response)
```

I've tried myself and using that you get one message at a time.

If you get some error try updating pubsub library to the last version:

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-pubsub
```

[In docs here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#streamingpull) you have more info about the pull method used in the code snippet:

> The Pull method relies on a request/response model:
>
> The application sends a request for messages. The server replies with
>   zero or more messages and closes the connection.

Answer (score 0):

As per the official documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/pubsub-io#using-record-ids):

> ...you can achieve exactly once processing of Pub/Sub message streams,
>   as PubsubIO de-duplicates messages based on custom message identifiers
>   or identifiers assigned by Pub/Sub.

So you should be able to use record IDs, i.e. identifiers for you messages, to allow for exactly-once processing across the boundary between Dataflow and other systems. To use record IDs, you invoke idLabel when constructing PubsubIO.Read or PubsubIO.Write transforms, passing a string value of your choice. In java this would be:

```
public PubsubIO.Read.Bound<T> idLabel(String idLabel)
```

This returns a transform that's like this one but that reads unique message IDs from the given message attribute.

Comment: I am not using it in Dataflow and also not using Java